# Generate a square color matrix in Latex with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can we generate this type of image using tikz package?

[image: ColoredMatrix]

Thank you all

Comment: probably, you can use some pieces from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274219/drawing-a-multicolored-grid-using-tikz

Comment: what kind of data do you want to generate it from ?

Comment: As there seems to be no colour pattern, you can do that with a simple `tabular` environment and the `\cellcolor` command from `colortbl`. Needless to summon `TikZ` for that.

Comment: @ Amit : in that codes, there is a black borders and I want to fill all the squares with the same color as in the image posted here.

@ Christoph: There is not a data, just I want to find a code that gives me the image

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315313/dynamically-filling-a-grid-with-tikz-from-a-data-array/315339#315339) question. Shouldn't be hard to adapt to your situation.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264182/drawing-a-really-large-binary-matrix-as-colored-grid/264223?s=1|0.4400#264223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the color pattern is given by a mathematical function, you might want to plot it using the `pgfplots` colormap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf] {exp(-((x)^2+(y)^2))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's also the `matrix plot` style in PGFPlots, which makes the squares centered on the coordinates (in your examples, the colour values of the squares represent the average of the four corner values)

Answer (score 4):

An example with `TiKZ` and a `colorseries` from `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolorseries{test}{rgb}{step}[rgb]{.95,.85,.55}{.17,.47,.37}
\resetcolorseries[35]{test}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}{
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,7}
        \fill[test!!+] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]